# Inserting hyperlinks into axis titles in R Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I'm hoping to embed hyperlinks into the x-axis of a plotly figure using R. A very nice example of what I'm trying to achieve is here:
https://help.plot.ly/adding-HTML-and-links-to-charts/#links-text-and-html-in-graphs

However, when I add links within the plot axis title annotations, it adds the text with the right formatting, but without the hyperlink itself (i.e., I can't navigate to the link within the plot).

I've tried removing anything superfluous (i.e, removing the option to open the link in a different tab - target='_blank').

Here is a example:

```r
  library(plotly)
  data(mtcars)
  p <- plot_ly() %>%
    add_trace(data = mtcars, 
              x = ~cyl, y = ~mpg, 
              type = 'scatter',
              mode = 'lines') %>%
    layout(autosize = T,
           title = "Test",
           xaxis = list(title = "<a href = https://www.nytimes.com/>The NY TIMES</a>"))
```

I'm expecting this plot, except with an actual link that takes me to the site. Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: try single quotes around your hyperlink URL: 'https://...'

Answer (score 3):

You just forgot some quotes around the link.

This should work fine:

```r
library(plotly)

data(mtcars)
p <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(data = mtcars, 
            x = ~cyl, y = ~mpg, 
            type = 'scatter',
            mode = 'lines') %>%
  layout(autosize = T,
         title = "Test",
         xaxis = list(title = "<a href = 'https://www.nytimes.com/'>The NY TIMES</a>"))
```